# How to change options in select list jsp using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I have this jsp page, where if you click a radio button, one subsection should become invisible and the option in the select list should get changed.

```
<center>
  <span class="ReportSubsectionTitle">Report Type</span>
                                    <br />
 <html:radio  styleId="detail" property="reportOutputStyleID" onclick="doSummary();" value="1" />Pending Funding
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <html:radio  styleId="summary" property="reportOutputStyleID" onclick="doDetail();" value="2" />Previously Funded
 </center>
 <script>
 function doDetail(){   
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeTop").checked = false;        
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeBottom").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeTop").disabled = true;    
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeBottom").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("dateRangeTypeID").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("dateRangeLabel").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("startDateStr").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("startDateLabel").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("startDateCalendarTrigger").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("endDateStr").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("endDateLabel").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("endDateCalendarTrigger").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("startDateTime").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("endDateTime").disabled = true;

    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeTop").style.visibility = "hidden";    
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeBottom").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("dateRangeTypeID").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("dateRangeLabel").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("startDateStr").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("startDateLabel").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("startDateCalendarTrigger").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("endDateStr").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("endDateLabel").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("endDateCalendarTrigger").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("startDateTime").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("endDateTime").style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.getElementById("DateSelection").style.visibility = "hidden";

 }
 function doSummary(){  

    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeTop").checked = true;     
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeBottom").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeTop").disabled = false;   
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeBottom").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("dateRangeTypeID").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("dateRangeLabel").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("startDateStr").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("startDateLabel").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("startDateCalendarTrigger").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("endDateStr").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("endDateLabel").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("endDateCalendarTrigger").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("startDateTime").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("endDateTime").disabled = false;

    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeTop").style.visibility = "visible";   
    document.getElementById("narrowByDateRangeBottom").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("dateRangeTypeID").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("dateRangeLabel").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("startDateStr").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("startDateLabel").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("startDateCalendarTrigger").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("endDateStr").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("endDateLabel").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("endDateCalendarTrigger").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("startDateTime").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("endDateTime").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("DateSelection").style.visibility = "visible";

 }
 </script>
```

Then, I have this subsection labelled "Date Selection" which I want to make invisble:

```
 <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <span id = "DateSelection" class="ReportSubsectionTitle">Date Selection</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <span class="ReportSubsectionTitle">Save Generated Report?</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
        <%@ include file="dateSelectionSection1.jsp" %>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" style="padding-left: 10px;">
        <%@ include file="savedReportNameField.jsp" %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I have a select list

```
  <span style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                    Date Type:
                                    <html:select property="dateTypeID">
                                        <html:options collection="dateTypes" property="id" labelProperty="name"/>
                                    </html:select>
                                </span>
```

I tried adding id to the select, but it gets an error saying tag not found. I want to change the selection under the dropdown and lock the selection.

I tried document.getElementById("dateTypeID").options[0].selected = 1. But, nothing changes after that.

I am new to JSP, and am not quite sure of how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say this is your select statement:

```
<select name="master" size="1">
  <option value="newsvalue">News</option>
  <option value="webmastervalue">Webmaster</option>
  <option value="techvalue">Tech</option>
</select>
```

In your javascript function that gets called after the user ticks the radio button you first remove all the options from the selectList like so:

```
document.myform.master.options.length=0;
```

Then you re-populate the selectList doing something like this:

```
document.myform.master.options[0]=new Option("Sports", "sportsvalue", true, false);  
document.myform.master.options[1]=new Option("Music", "musicvalue", false, false);
document.myform.master.options[2]=new Option("Movies", "moviesvalue", false, false);
```

The datatypes for the "new Option()" function being:

```
new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected);
```

So this doesn't get handled anyway different in a JSP than it would in a HTML page. Hope you found this usefull :-)